# RMagick::Image.from_blob method don't work

Tags: ruby, svg, rmagick

I using Ruby, Sinatra and RMagick

I wont take browser icon (.svg file), add to icon text - version of browser - and return new .svg as respond to user

I wont open .svg as string, add some lines with my text and save this as new .svg file using RMagick.

but method `to_blob` and `from_blob` doesn't work correct

```
# myapp.rb 

require 'sinatra'
require 'rmagick'

get '/test/:browser' do
  img = Magick::Image::read("icons/default/#{params[:browser]}.svg")[0]
  str = img.to_blob
  "<textarea name='image' cols='100' rows='100'>#{str}</textarea>"
end
```

documentation from https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#to_blob

> img.to_blob [ { optional arguments } ]-> string
>
> Description: Creates a Binary Large OBject, a direct-to-memory version
>   of the image.

chrome.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="15.5 15.5 224.5 224.5">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient cy="0" cx="0.5" id="r">
     <stop stop-color="#f06b59"/>
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="#df2227"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient r="0.76" cy="0.3" cx="0.65" id="g">
     <stop offset="0.65" stop-color="#4cb749"/>
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="#388b41"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient r="0.8" cy="0.25" cx="0.36" id="y">
     <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#FCD209"/>
     <stop offset="0.7" stop-color="#f7c616"/>
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="#bc821e"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient r="1" cy="0" cx="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" id="cf">
     <stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#7FB3DF"/>
     <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="#0F5B94"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="cb" r="1" cy="0" cx="0.5">
     <stop offset="0" stop-color="#F6F0EE"/>
     <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ddd"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="m198,148a70,70 0 0 0 -140,0l20,0a50,50 0 0 1 100,0" fill-opacity="0.1"/>
  <circle r="45" cx="127.5" cy="127.6" fill="url(#cf)" stroke="url(#cb)" stroke-width="9" />
  <path d="m228,78a112,112 0 0 0 -193,-13l45,78a50,50 0 0 1 47,-65" fill="url(#r)"/>
  <path d="m35,65a112,112 0 0 0 84,174l47,-80a50,50 0 0 1 -86,-16" fill="url(#g)"/>
  <path d="m119,239a112,112 0 0 0 109,-161l-101,0a50,50 0 0 1 39,81" fill="url(#y)"/>
  <path d="m35,65l45,78a50,50 0 0 1 2,-34l-45,-47" opacity="0.075"/>
  <path d="m119,239l47,-80a50,50 0 0 1 -29,17l-20,63" opacity="0.05"/>
  <path d="m228,78l-101,0a50,50 0 0 1 39,19l64,-16" opacity="0.05"/>
</svg>
```

But to_blob return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="225" height="225">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="1" cy="0" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="2" cy="0" r="1" fill="white"/>
==============================
about 50 000 such lines here
if this save to file, size of file will be about 3 MB
==============================
  <circle cx="220" cy="224" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="221" cy="224" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="222" cy="224" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="223" cy="224" r="1" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="224" cy="224" r="1" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

What I doing wrong?

Or, if you have another idea how to do this task - please, share.

Comment: Can you specify the input SVG and the expected output?

Comment: add code to question

Answer (score -2):

```
get '/test/:browser' do
  image = File.open('icons/default/chrome.svg')
  blob = image.read
  "<textarea name='image' cols='100' rows='100'>#{blob}</textarea>"
end
```

This is what i need.
First `open` file, then use `read` method. 
In this case all work correct and `.to_blob` not needed